# Flask : Can't get value request.method

Tags: python, flask

I have a problem, when i call `request.method`, it has value `get`, although in form, i use `post` method. Please help me thank you!

#### my controller

```
def status_sj():
    o = OdooUtility()
    form = SearchForm()
    controls = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        controls = "oke"
    return render_template('order_entry_v2/status_sj.html', control=controls, form=form)
```

#### view html

```
    <form method=" POST">
            <div class="container-fluid row pull-12">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin: 0.2px; padding: 0.2px;">
                        {{ form.month(class_ = 'form-control') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin: 0.2px; padding: 0.2px;">
                    {{ form.year(class_ = 'form-control') }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin: 0.2px; padding: 0.2px;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cari</button>
                </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems, you are missing `POST` in methods list in the **decorator** above your view function

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def status_sj():
    [..]
```

Comment: i have add methods in the decorator, but its no works